# Laravel collection .each() + array_push

Tags: php, laravel-5

need help regarding array_push inside .each() method on laravel. I cannot get the container array on this code:

```
$imagesData = array();
collect($data['images'])->each(function($v, $k) use($imagesData){

    $v['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $v['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $v['image_id'] = $v['image_id'];
    $v['settings'] = json_encode($v['settings']);

    array_push($imagesData, $v);

});

$result = Images::insert($imagesData, true);
```

Basically, the code above I want to iterate the data inside .each() and then push it to array container and insert it by batch.
NOTE: when i use foreach there will be no problem, but I need to use .each() instead of foreach.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the [`Collection::map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) method is a much more readable way to do the same thing:

```
$imagesData = collect($data['images'])
    ->map(function($item) {

        $item['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $item['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $item['image_id'] = $item['image_id'];
        $item['settings'] = json_encode($item['settings']);

        return $item;
    })
    ->all();

$result = Images::insert($imagesData, true);
```

`map` iterates over the array the same way as `each` does. The difference is that `each` does not return anything (so you need to build the new array yourself) while `map` automatically builds a new collection of the items you `return` inside the function. After `map`, you use `all` to return the results as a plain array.

Answer (score 26):

Because you want to change the original `$imageData`, you need to refer to this variable instead of just copying the value of it. This is done by using an ampersand `&`.

```
collect($data['images'])->each(function($v, $k) use(&$imagesData){
    // ...
});
```