# Add array item inside grouped by array in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, group-by

I have an array in laravel named `$destinations` and the values are:

```
    Collection {#391 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "Chicago, Illinois" => Collection {#398 ▼
          #items: array:10 [▶]
        }
        "New York City, New York" => Collection {#403 ▼
          #items: array:10 [▶]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This array is grouped by city name just like **Chicago** and **New York**, now I want to add one **array** item after the city name, it should be like this:

```
Collection {#391 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Chicago, Illinois" => Collection {#398 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▶]
    "days" => "2"
    }
    "New York City, New York" => Collection {#403 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▶]
    "days" => "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to use `array_merge` when i loop the array, I use `foreach($destinations as $key => $destination)` in the looping, basically the `$key` will return increment number like **0**, **1**, **2**, etc but in this case it return the city name. Anyone knows how to do it? or how to make the `$key` still increment number after grouped by in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your `$destinations` variable is a collection. So you can iterate through it using `each` method.

for example:

```
$destinations = $destinations->each(function ($item, $key) {
    // You can modify $item here
    // $item['days'] = <no_of_days>;
});
```

To get the increment number, you can do something like this:

```
$element_position = 0;
$destinations = $destinations->each(function ($item, $key) use ($element_position) {
        // You can modify $item here
        // $item['days'] = <no_of_days>;
        // You can get the $element_position here
        // Iterate $element_position
        $element_position++;
});
```

Comment: it works, but still I can't get the key number increment, is there any way to get the $key index number? because right now the $key contain the city name

Comment: the $item['days'] value should be the $key index number, so it is like 0, 1, 2.  not the city names

Comment: Answer updated. Check if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: The $element_position not incremented, still zero in each looping

Comment: I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773475/laravel-collection-each-array-push and I add & in each function like this each(function ($item, $key) use (&$element_position) and now it works like a charm